# creating a selector with variables when the content of the variable has a quote

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".responsivetable").on("click", "td", function() {
            var content = $(this).text();
            var index = ($(this).index());
            $(".responsivetable tr td:nth-child(" + (index + 1) + "):contains('" + content + "')").addClass('kleur1');

        });
    });
```

What it does is when you click on a table cell (td) all other td's in the same column, with the same content, get a specific class.

So when you click in a column with names on 'John', all cells in that column with 'John' get a cssclass.

This works, but not when the content contains a single quote, like **nov '16**.

I think it is because the string concatenation breaks but how do I fix this?

(Other ways to solve the thing I'm trying to accomplish are welcome too.)

Comment: Instead of `:contains('" + content + "')` try using `:contains(" + content + ")`

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes, sorry I didn't know how to fix this :-S

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. It has a problem description, the current attempt in syntactically valid code, desired outcome, proper tags, a proper title. I'm not sure what's missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".responsivetable").on("click", "td", function() {
    var content = $.trim( $(this).text() ).toLowerCase(),
        index = $(this).index() + 1,
        $candidates = $(".responsivetable tr td:nth-child(" + index + ")");

    $candidates
        .removeClass("kleur1")
        .filter(function () {      
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(content) > -1;
        })
        .addClass('kleur1');
});
```

Alternative:

```
$(".responsivetable").on("click", "td", function() {
    var content = $.trim( $(this).text() ).toLowerCase(),
        index = $(this).index() + 1,
        $candidates = $(".responsivetable tr td:nth-child(" + index + ")");

    $candidates
        .toggleClass("kleur1", function () {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(content) > -1;
        });
});
```

Comment: Could you explain why `:contains()` won't work in this case? And anyway this is different behaviour, here it is case insensitive unlike the OP's posted code. But i guess this doesn't really matter here

Comment: I have no desire to occupy myself with thinking of all the ways of escaping all kinds of input values properly so that the selector string does not break. That's a waste of time, `.filter()` is way more appropriate here. Plus, `:contains()` is case-sensitive and white-space-sensitive with no way of changing this.

Comment: OK but posting only code answer doesn't really help (usually) and specifically if it changes the original behaviour. BUT imho you are correct, OP has better to use `filter()` here

Comment: In fact, I deliberately used `toLowerCase()` in my answer to showcase one of the benefits of using `.filter()` instead of `.contains()`. :)

Comment: Very nice. I had never heard of the `filter()` method. I thought all the selectors where actually filters, but this works really good.

Comment: I recommend to take half an hour and scroll through the list of available jQuery core functions. You might be surprised what other things you've been missing. BTW, a nice way to browse official documentation is http://devdocs.io/